# Copy An Image to A Specific Coordinate

Tags: java

I have a program that works well; however, I want to be able to copy an earth image to a different section of the new image that is created. For example, if I could place the picture of the Earth on the bottom left corner instead of the top left corner.

```
import java.awt.*;
public class CopyCatDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Picture sourcePicture = new Picture("earth.jpg");
        System.out.println("Width: " + sourcePicture.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Height: " + sourcePicture.getHeight());
        Picture targetPicture1 = new Picture(800,800);
        targetPicture1.setAllPixelsToAColor(Color.BLACK);

        Pixel sourcePixel, targetPixel = null;
        Color sourceColor, targetColor = null;

        for(int y = 0; y < sourcePicture.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < sourcePicture.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                sourcePixel = sourcePicture.getPixel(x,y);
                sourceColor = sourcePixel.getColor();
                targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x,y);
                targetPixel.setColor(sourceColor);         
            }
        }

        sourcePicture.show();
        targetPicture1.show();
        targetPicture1.write("NewFile.jpg");
    }//end of main method
}//end of class
```

So, if someone could please demonstrate how to edit this code to get the picture of the Earth to appear on the bottom left corner as an example on the new target image that would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is `Picture`?

Comment: It's just necessary to create a Picture object. Similar to how int is used for an integer, or how String is used for a string. This is just for pictures that are created.

Comment: Ok, then what namespace is `Picture` in?

Comment: `It's just necessary to create a Picture object` But the class definition is not provided...it may not be necessary to solve the issue but it helps to disclose unknowns so guesses are not necessary

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry I'm fairly new to Java, so I'm not sure if I can give you the information you need. Would you still be able to take a crack at moving the Earth image to different coordinates?

Comment: Alright that makes sense! With that information I can basically move it anywhere! Thank you for dealing with someone new to Java like myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I could place the picture of the Earth on the bottom left corner instead of the top left corner.

Do the proper math to offset the coordinates - for example to move to the bottom left you need to vertically offset the target pixel - in other words offset the y value for the target pixel by the height of the target minus the height of the source

```
int vOffset = targetPicture1.getHeight() - sourcePicture.getHeight();
//
targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x, vOffset + y);
```